# JSF fails to evaluate Java objects mapped to input fields

Tags: jsf, jstl

I have a JSF application in which I use JSF h:inputText for accepting user data. I bind the input fields to java objects using managed beans which is mostly normal.

The data entered in the HTML form is saved periodically using sequential ajax calls. Sometimes the periodic save fails with error in looking up the mapped object to the input field(the error message says it can not find the java object). This may not happen for the next call to save the data though nothing is changed in the application. I can't figure out the pattern to reproduce this bug. When I try to debug printing the object values it works fine too. In the input value mapping I have nested objects which I suspect may have something to do with the error.

Here is the code snippet in JSF page.

```
<c:forEach var="doc"
            items="#{trim.trim.act.relationship['patientSurgeons'].act.relationshipsList['physician']}"
            varStatus="physicianIndex">
            <table>
                <tr>

                    <td><h:inputText
                            id="firstName#{physicianIndex.index}" placeholder="first name"
                            value="#{doc.act.participation['surgeon'].role.player.name.EN['L'].parts[0].ST.value}"
                            class="sidebyside small" />
                        </td>
```

Here is how the exception stack trace

> 15:52:55,239 ERROR [[Faces Servlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
>   javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /META-INF/tags/wizard/inputTextWithPlaceholder.xhtml @15,86 value="#{value}": /wizard/questionnaireWiz/patientPhysicians.xhtml @73,36 value="#{doc.act.participation['surgeon'].role.player.name.EN['L'].parts[0].ST.value}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'doc' resolved to null
>       at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:62)
>       at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:81)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:934)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:860)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1065)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:666)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:229)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1033)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:662)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:100)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:244)

What could I be missing here?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to access a list or array (parts[0]). Are you sure that the list really contains a value for index zero?

Answer (score 0):

This construct will fail like that when the value behind `<c:forEach items>` is not available during process validations phase of the postback request and hence `#{doc}` evaluates to `null`. For example, because the `#{trim}` is a request scoped bean whose data is initialized via a `<f:viewParam>`. Making it a view scoped bean (and in case you're using Mojarra, ensuring that you're using at least 2.1.18), should fix it.

Comment: it's unfortunate that we are using JSF1.x with facelets. I can't upgrade to 2.0 to be able to use view scope. Do you have any other recommendations for an alternate bug fix? Thank you BalusC